# select a column name with apostroph from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table where there is a column with this name : **bureau d'étude**

When I do a select :

```
String sql = "select bureau d'étude from table";
```

the server show me a syntax error. How to hide or replace this apostrophe ?

Comment: this is an error because of the space between `bureau` and `d'étude`.  Try `select \`bureau d''étude\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String sql = "select `bureau d''étude` from table";
```

Since there is a space in the column name make sure you encapsulate it with `.

Furthermore, you can escape a single quote with another single quote.

Answer (score 3):

You should really use a `PreparedStatement` to avoid these problems and thus SQL injections:

```
PreparedStatement statementSelect;

String sql = "select ? from ?";

try
{
  statementSelect = myConnection.prepareStatement(sql);

  statementSelect.setString(1,"bureau d'étude");
  statementSelect.setString(2,"table");
  statementSelect.executeQuery();
}
catch (SQLException e )
{
  //handle this
}
```

Comment: i use truly a prepared statement. i put the ? in WHERE clause, and because i work with jdbcTemplate and I must get the result into the bean by getters and sitters, that solution make my code very big. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can Try following:

```
String sql = "select [bureau d''étude] from table";
```